# Bitwise OR operation with 0b transform a given number in negative

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-and

I need to perform certain operations with bitwise operators, let's say we have this 40 bit unsigned integer:

`1071698660929` when I apply to it a `OR` operator and an unsigned right shift operator I got this negative integer

**Input**: `(1071698660929 >>> 0) | 0b0`

**Output**:  `-2043163071`

I noticed that as long as the number is 31 bit long I don't have any problem adding a `0B0` but when the number is greater than 31 bit it becomes negative even though I'm using the unsigned right shift operator:

32 bits binary return `-1`: `(0b11111111111111111111111111111111 >>> 0) | 0`

31 bits binary return `2147483647` : `(0b1111111111111111111111111111111 >>> 0) | 0`

So I have a couple of questions:

1. Why the numbers above are becoming negative if I'm using a right shift operator? What I understand is that the MAX safe integer in **javascript** is 53 bit long `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.toString(2).length` so I'm within the integer safe boundaries.
2. What could I do to make this `(1071698660929 >>> 0) | 0b0` returns
   `1071698660929` instead of `-2043163071`?

Comment: Wow! @raina77ow thanks so much for this marvelous explanation, what happened above I got negative values because some bits were discarded even the bit that indicates the (unsigned right shift)?

Comment: The type of operation doesn't have to do anything with it; it's that explicit conversion done on operand itself.

Comment: @raina77ow Care to make that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitwise operators implicitly convert their operands to 32-bit integers (signed or unsigned, depending on operator). In process, numbers with more than 32 bits get their most significant bits [discarded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND#description):

```
Before: 11100110111110100000000000000110000000000001
After:              10100000000000000110000000000001
```

The only exception of this rule is (relatively) new kid on the primitive block, [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)  type: all the bitwise ops (`&`, `|`, `^`) and almost all the shifts are [overloaded](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator) for that type.

This opens a way out of your problem: just use `BigInt` instead of plain `number`, either explicitly, like this:

```
const bigIntee = BigInt(1071698660929); // note no `new` here!
```

... or, if you actually have to use literal, by appending `n` to it:

```
const bigIntee = 1071698660929n; // also works
```

Note that if one operand is `BigInt`, another should be `BigInt` as well. So this...

```
bigIntee | 0
```

... will make JS angry with your pathetic attempts of getting back to happy type-anarchy times of 90s. To be more specific, you'll get a TypeError thrown right at you:

```
Cannot mix BigInt and other types, use explicit conversions
```

This is easily fixable, though: just apply either of aforementioned conversion tricks to the second operand as well.

```
bigIntee | 0n 
// or bigIntee | BigInt(0)
```

Both works. Disregard `0` being, well, not really a *Biggus Integerus* kind; type safety reigns here.

Still, there's a problem: `>>>` (unsigned right shift operator) cannot be used on BigInts. If you attempt to go with it, you'll get a pretty specific error:

```
bigIntee >>> 0n
// Uncaught TypeError: BigInts have no unsigned right shift, use >> instead
```

... which makes total sense (and us wishing all the errors thrown by JS were **that** specific).